# SQL Server : Search Between Characters in UK Postcode Unit Field

Tags: sql-server

As a solution to a postcode lookup I have split a postcode database into a the separate columns for Area, District, Sector, Unit. I have even split out the characters that could be in District like the A and B in W1A and W1B etc.

I am wanting to search for a postcode like B46 3BA and have got as far as returning details as below.

[image: Sql Server Manager View]

The SQL query used thus far is

```
SELECT     
    StationID, FromPostcode, ToPostcode, FromPostCodeArea, 
    FromPostCodeDistrict, FromPostCodeDistrictChar, 
    FromPostCodeSector, FromPostCodeUnit,
    ToPostCodeArea, ToPostCodeDistrict, 
    ToPostCodeDistrictChar, ToPostCodeSector, ToPostCodeUnit
FROM
    Station
WHERE     
    (FromPostCodeArea = 'B') 
    AND (3 BETWEEN FromPostCodeSector AND ToPostCodeSector) 
    AND (46 BETWEEN FromPostCodeDistrict AND ToPostCodeDistrict)
```

My main issues for legacy application reasons is I do not have access to the Select query and can only change the `WHERE` clause. I just need it to return the single row in this case row with stationid 3321.

But I am totally lost on how to take this any further

Answer As suggested by Jamie makes the sql

```
SELECT     
    StationID, FromPostcode, ToPostcode, FromPostCodeArea, 
    FromPostCodeDistrict, FromPostCodeDistrictChar, 
    FromPostCodeSector, FromPostCodeUnit,
    ToPostCodeArea, ToPostCodeDistrict, 
    ToPostCodeDistrictChar, ToPostCodeSector, ToPostCodeUnit
FROM
Station
WHERE     
    (FromPostCodeArea = 'B') 
    AND (3 BETWEEN FromPostCodeSector AND ToPostCodeSector) 
    AND (46 BETWEEN FromPostCodeDistrict AND ToPostCodeDistrict)
    AND ('B46 3BA' BETWEEN FromPostCode AND ToPostCode)
```

Seems to do the trick on a test run of 2000 random postcodes.

Comment: wouldnt  `AND 'B46 3BA' BETWEEN FromPostcode and ToPostcode` work?

Comment: interesting... at first glance I don't see a reason for it to not work. could you create a SQLfiddle out of this in order to have a playfield ?

Comment: Thanks JamieD77, Having tried it on a few postcodes this does seem to work with the other ANDS. Need to try it on a massive range.